# Backup and Restore AWS RDS Aurora cluster

Tags: postgresql, backup, amazon-rds, restore, amazon-aurora

I would like to backup every single PostgreSql database of my AWS RDS Cluster (Aurora DB Engine). Are there some managed tools (like Veeam or N2WS) or best practices, how to backup and restore a single database or schema from AWS S3?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use automatic backup combined with manual backup for Aurora PostgreSql database. For automatic backup, the max retention period is 35 days, and support any point in time restore and recovery. However, if you need a backup beyond the backup retention period (35 days), you can also take a snapshot of the data in your cluster volume.

If you use third-party tools, such as Veeam, it will also invoke AWS RDS snapshot API to take the backup, so the underly mechanism is the same.

You can also use the pg_dump utility for backing up the RDS for PostgreSQL database, and run pg_dump on read replica to minimize the performance impact to the primary database.